# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' Python urllib2

Tags: python, http, error-handling, compiler-errors, urllib2

I keep getting this error for some reason and I can't figure out why. I'm fairly new to Python so please bear with me. 
The error i'm getting is: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

This is my code:

```
import re, urllib2
for i in range(0, 6):
    url = "http://www.gametracker.com/search/garrysmod/?searchipp=50&searchpge=  {0}#search".format(i)
    print url
    urlr = url.read()
    ip = re.compile(r"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?):\d{1,6}\b")
    print ip.findall(urlr)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to make the request using [`urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen):

```
urlr = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Besides, to avoid `Bad request` error, eliminate extra spaces from the `url`:

```
url = "http://www.gametracker.com/search/garrysmod/?searchipp=50&searchpge=  {0}#search".format(i)
#                                                                          ^
```